# How to call update stored procedure from .NET Core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Admin_SetUserToIsDeleted] 
    (@bb_customer_id int) 
AS
    DECLARE @bb_customer_id_local INT
    SET @bb_customer_id_local = @bb_customer_id

    BEGIN TRAN 
        UPDATE dbo.bb_customer_login_identification WITH (rowlock) 
        SET is_deleted = 1 
        WHERE bb_customer_id = @bb_customer_id_local

        UPDATE dbo.bb_customer 
        SET is_deleted = 1 
        WHERE bb_customer_id = @bb_customer_id_local

    COMMIT TRAN
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
public object ExecuteAdminUserDeleted(int CustomerID)
{

var CustParam = new SqlParameter("@bb_customer_id", CustomerID);

_dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Admin_SetUserToIsDeleted @bb_customer_id=@bb_customer_id", CustParam);

}
```

If you're returning data from the stored procedure, you have to call it differently (FromSqlRaw) and scaffold a database class to hold the returned data.